# What is the best way to show total sales and breakdown of the total?

Tags: design, interface, data, users

Basically, I need to show the total amt of sales made each week. For this case, let's put the figure at 200.

Now, I need to further breakdown this figure and segment them according to salesperson. e.g. Sally made 20 sales, John made 100 sales and Tom made 80 sales (total 200).

Is a pie-chart the best way to show this type of data?

Problem with the piechart is that if the sales people gets more than 8 or more, it starts getting messy and hard to read.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little. It's not clear in what context you need to represent your sales - e.g. are we talking an Excel spreadsheet?  Will it be primarily viewed on screen, or as a printout? Any other info we should know?

Comment: The information is meant to be displayed on a website, as part of the Admin control panel UI. It's for the Administrator to read and view the stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pie charts are not good when you have to compare. Also, they have a limit of how many values to represent.

I would recommend a horizontal bar chart. Comparisons are much more easy and you can have many values. Also, the names of the employees are much more easy to read.

Keep the bar chart simple : Do not add grid-lines. X-axis values are not needed. Place the value of each bar on top. Place the total sales at the top of the chart.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think that weekly total sales also be different from each other. In order to show overall performance, two different interconnected bar-chart can be a good solution for your problem.

[image]

Comment: Hi, tks a lot. Could you explain how to use and read this kind of inter-connected bar chart? Tks! :-)

Comment: In my simple example, the first one is based on the weeks, total sales and the fragmentation by workers. In the second chart, the pieces in the first chart create another chart based on worker performance, color coding is used for that. Manager can say , hey this worker two shows good performance in long time  while, orange becomes less by time and blue worker, fluctuates the most. From simple bar charts to complex bar charts when it is needed is better way from my experiences.

Comment: Wow, this is darn awesome! I finally understand now! Ah, the genius of this thinking! Tks! :-)